Retrieving beta distribution parameters, alpha and beta, from mode and variance
Is it possible to decide the parameters of beta distribution ,alpha and beta, when mode and variance are given? I know the two parameters can be decided from mean and variance as:
$E[X] = \dfrac{a}{a+b}$
$Var[X] = \dfrac{ab}{(a+b)^2(a+b+1)}$
$a = E[X]^2(1-E[X])\dfrac{1}{Var[X]} - E[X]$
$b = \dfrac{a}{E[X]} - a$
Is there any equations to get alpha and beta from mode and variance? (I’m thinking it under $a > 1$ and $b > 1$.
I have read this post Calculating the parameters of a Beta distribution with known mode and variance but I can’t understand the answer and the post is old. The thread seems suggest an approximation method (If I understand it correctly). But for my case, retrieving alpha and beta from mode and variance (like from E[X] and Var[X] above) is preferable because I want to perform a Bayesian modeling as:
$ProportionData \sim Beta(a, b)$
$a = f_1(mode, variance)$
$b = f_2(mode, variance)$
where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are functions of determining alpha and beta from mode and variance (what I need). Then, mode and variance are dependent on other variables.
I am new to these probability problem and Bayesian statistics, so in the above questions there may be oversights that makes my question nonsense. If there are, I would really appreciate it if you could point them out to me.
Thank you very much

As @whuber says in the linked (and duplicate) question: Solve the equations numerically. The explicit formulas seem to be extremely messy and not really worth it. The numerical solutions are not approximations but exact (up to the numerical precision).

Just solve the equations numerically. This is not an approximation but exact. Here is an implementation in R:
# Solver
library("nleqslv")

# System of two equations
fn <- function(pars, var, mode) {
  sum_pars <- sum(pars)
  eq_m <- (pars[1] - 1)/(sum_pars - 2) - mode
  eq_v <- prod(pars)/(sum_pars^2*(sum_pars + 1)) - var
  
  return(c(eq_m, eq_v))
}

# Test with parameters
true_pars <- c(5.5, 2.15)

# Calculate the mode and variance
true_mode <- (true_pars[1] - 1)/(sum(true_pars) - 2)
true_var <-  prod(true_pars)/(sum(true_pars)^2*(sum(true_pars) + 1))

# Informed guess for a
guess_a <- 1 + true_mode^2*(1 - true_mode)/true_var

# Solve equations
res <- nleqslv(c(guess_a, 1), fn, var = true_var, mode = true_mode)
res$x
[1] 5.50 2.15

In the function, pars is a vector of length 2 containing the two parameters of the beta distribution. var and mode are the desired variance and mode.
One word of caution: In the function above, we assume that $\alpha, \beta>1$ so that a single mode in $(0, 1)$ exists. Otherwise, the mode can be either any value in $(0, 1)$ if $\alpha = \beta = 1$, be bimodal if $\alpha, \beta <1$ or $0$ if $\alpha\leq 1, \beta\geq 1, \alpha\neq\beta$ or $1$ if $\alpha\geq 1, \beta\leq 1, \alpha\neq\beta$.

Thank you very much!! I understand what people do! A will use stan, which seems have solver function as R. Thank you very much!

@AKIRA28 If you find this answer helpful, remember to upvote and accept it.

You need to solve a system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
V[X] = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}\\
M[X] = \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
($M[X]$ being the mode)

Thank you very much for your replying. I tried it once but is there any explicit formula like "a = xxxxx" and "b = xxxxx", rather than implicit formula?

@AKIRA28 it's probably easier using optimization than finding a closed form, but at that piont depends what's your programming language (for R, check the other answer)

I understand your comment now. Implicit formula can be solved and various languages have solver function. Thank you very much for your kind comment!
